# marshmallow schema load return just values

Tags: python, flask, deserialization, marshmallow

When I use like below

```
 data , error = schema.load( json_data )
```

data object contains only values not keys but  json_data is a valid dict.
and if I just use

```
MyModel = _mymodel(**json_data)
```

it works. But if I use below inside of my schema

```
@post_load
def create_model(self, data):    
  return MyModel(**data)
```

I get error

> AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'get'

Anyone has any idea? Why "data" contains only value and does not return dictionary like the examples stated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation [here](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html) there are two methods similar to each others.

1. [load](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.load)(data, many=None, partial=None)

   > Deserialize a data structure to an object defined by this Schema’s fields and make_object().

Another is

2. [loads](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.loads)(json_data, many=None, *args, **kwargs)

   > Same as load(), except it takes a JSON string as input.

So you need to use `loads()` instead of `load()` if you have json data.

Comment: To clarify, use loads if you have JSON string data